How to Independently Control the Motion of a Sphere Using Two Rotational Joints in Gazebo?
Description
I am working with Gazebo and ROS2 foxy to create a manipulator simulation model. My manipulators are two balls, named as ball0 and ball1. Now I want ball1 to rotate independently around the X and Y axes using two rotational joints (ball1_joint_x and ball1_joint_y).

Here are the issue I am facing:
I have tried several configurations:

Directly attaching ball1 as a child of both joints, but Gazebo only allows one joint to control the link.

Add two intermediate links ball1_x and ball1_y, then connect them to ball1 via fixed joints, but this still fails to achieve independent control
No matter how I configure the model, only one joint can control the sphere at a time. The other joint becomes non-functional or ignored by Gazebo.
Below is my current URDF configuration:
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <robot name="disg13" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
     <link name="world" />
     <joint name="ball0_fixed_joint" type="fixed">
     <parent link="world"/>
     <child link="ball0"/>
     <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
 </joint>
 <link name="ball0" >
     <inertial>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <mass value="0.75" />
         <inertia ixx="0.000979" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000979" iyz="0" izz="0.000979" />
     </inertial>
     <visual>
         <geometry>
         <mesh filename="package://disg13/meshes/ball.dae" />
         </geometry>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <material name="black">
                     <color rgba="0.7 0.5 0 0.5" />
                 </material>
     </visual>
     <collision>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <geometry>
             <mesh filename="package://disg13/meshes/ball.dae" />
         </geometry>
     </collision>
 </link>
 <link name="ball1_x">
     <inertial>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <mass value="0.001" />
         <inertia ixx="0.000001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.000001" />
         </inertial>
 </link>
 <link name="ball1_y">
             <inertial>
             <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <mass value="0.001" />
             <inertia ixx="0.000001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.000001" />
             </inertial>
 </link>
 <link name="ball1_xy">
             <inertial>
             <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <mass value="0.001" />
             <inertia ixx="0.000001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.000001" />
             </inertial>
     </link>
 <joint name="ball1_joint_x" type="continuous">
         <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <parent link="ball0" />
         <child link="ball1_x" />
         <axis xyz="1 0 0" /> 
         <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
 </joint>
 <joint name="ball1_joint_fixed_x" type="fixed">
             <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <parent link="ball1_x" />
             <child link="ball1_xy" />
 </joint>
 <joint name="ball1_joint_fixed_y" type="fixed">
             <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <parent link="ball1_y" />
             <child link="ball1_xy" />
 </joint>
 <joint name="ball1_joint_fixed_xy" type="fixed">
             <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
             <parent link="ball1_xy" />
             <child link="ball1" />
     </joint>
 <joint name="ball1_joint_y" type="continuous">
     <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <parent link="ball0" />
     <child link="ball1_y" />
     <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
     <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
 </joint>
 <link name="ball1" >
     <inertial>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0.081" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <mass value="0.75" />
         <inertia ixx="0.000979" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000979" iyz="0" izz="0.000979" />
     </inertial>
     <visual>
         <geometry>
         <mesh filename="package://disg13/meshes/ball.dae" />
         </geometry>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0.081" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <material name="black">
             <color rgba="0.7 0.5 0 0.5" />
         </material>
     </visual>
     <collision>
         <origin xyz="0 0 0.081" rpy="0 0 0" />
         <geometry>
             <mesh filename="package://disg13/meshes/ball.dae" />
         </geometry>
     </collision>
 </link>
 <gazebo>
     <plugin name="joint_state_publisher_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_state_publisher.so">
         <update_rate>20</update_rate>
         <joint_name>ball1_joint_x</joint_name>
         <joint_name>ball1_joint_y</joint_name>
     </plugin>
 </gazebo>
 <gazebo>
     <plugin name="gazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory" filename="libgazebo_ros_joint_pose_trajectory.so">
             <update_rate>20</update_rate>
     </plugin>
 </gazebo>
 <gazebo>
     <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
         <parameters>/home/yifu/yifu/disg13/config/ball1_controller.yaml</parameters>
         <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
     </plugin>
 </gazebo>
 <transmission name="transmission_arm_joint">
     <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
     <joint name="ball1_joint_x">
             <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
     </joint>
     <joint name="ball1_joint_y">
                     <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
     </joint>
 </transmission>



My Environment
ROS Version: ROS2 Foxy
Gazebo Version: Gazebo 11
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
I've been working on this issue several weeks and I would be grateful if someone could look into it and give some suggestions. Thanks!
